# How to move a div up and down infinitely in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to do the simple task of moving a div up and down to give a floating/hovering effect using bottom instead of top.

I'm new to CSS and keyframes! As you can probably tell. But here is what I have tried and it didn't seem to do anything:

```css
.Mail {
  margin-top: -77px;
  margin-left: 791px;
  animation: MoveUpDown 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes MoveUpDown {
  0%, 100% {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  50% {
    bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<i class="Mail fas fa-envelope"></i>
```

Comment: you need to position the element (anything non static) - top and bottom only work on positioned elements

Comment: So how shall I do that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set its `position` to `absolute` in order for the `bottom` *property* to take effect:

```css
.Mail {
  margin-top: -77px;
  margin-left: 791px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: MoveUpDown 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes MoveUpDown {
  50% {bottom: 20px}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<i class="Mail fas fa-envelope"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

`bottom`, `top`, `right`, `left` need a `position` property. The default `position` value is `static` which has *no effect* as [MDN Explained here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/bottom). I highly recommend reading the `bottom` guide to see its effect with different `position` values!

Anyways, your `animation` code is correct. However, you need to understand how the `position` property work in CSS to avoid similar mistakes.

*P.S: Start by understanding the following:
`relative`
`absolute`
`fixed`, here is a great resource from [MDN Web Docs about Positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)*

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who's looking for the same thing, here is a simpler answer using `transform: translateY();`:

```css
.moving-div{
margin-top:100px;
    animation-name: move;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes move {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(25%);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-25%);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="moving-div">
I am moving up and down
</div>
```